# (Q) Subject is QML - How Can I Delay Usage in Keys.onPressed Function

Tags: qt, qml

I try to increase the value in every 1 second even though the related key is pressed. For example, if I press the X key for 5 seconds, I want the value of x to be 5. Can you give suggestions on this subject?

```
function delay(delayTime, cb) {
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.interval = delayTime;
  timer.repeat = false;
  timer.triggered.connect(cb);
  timer.start();
}
Keys.onPressed: {
  if (event.key === Qt.Key_X ) {
    delay(1000, function() {
      current = Math.min(current + 1, 100);
    });        
  }
```

I do it this way, but there is no delay when I hold it down. It only works when I step the key on and off.

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous question, you want to measure the time between the pressed and released events. But I made a quick test and I ran into [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57335) bug dealing with auto-repeating keys. It sounds like it only affects linux, so maybe that won't matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Here if you press any keys it will display how long you have pressed that key. This will work for all keys

```
    Item{
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true
    property int current: 0
    property var map:({})
    Timer{id:tmr;interval: 1000;running: false;repeat:true;onTriggered:parent.current=parent.current+1;}
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (!event.isAutoRepeat) {
            var v=String.fromCharCode(event.key)
            current=(map[v]===undefined)?0:map[v]
            tmr.restart()
        }
    }
    Keys.onReleased: {
        if (!event.isAutoRepeat  ) {
            tmr.stop()
            var v=String.fromCharCode(event.key)
            map[v]=current
            console.log(map[v])
            console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but when I press and hold the button it doesn't work. I use like that, sorry for I don't know how to view code when I commenting.

    
Keys.onPressed: {

        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Q ) {
            var v=String.fromCharCode(event.key)
            current=(map[v]===undefined)?0:map[v]
            tmr.restart()
            current = Math.min(current + 1, 100);
        }
    }

Comment: Did you try the whole code? its actually  working for me when you press and hold.The main thing to note here is the isAutoRepeat property, and stopping the timer on keys.onReleased.

Comment: Yes, I  tried all the code.  I write the counter function under the  tmr.restart() function, but When I holding the key down, the value increases rapidly, saying 1-2-3-4-5-6 then the value returns to 2. When I keep pressing, the value stays constant at 2 last. No more changes.